# Impulse and Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

When two identical bodies are dropped from different heights, the one falling from a greater height will have  more momentum hence a greater impact on the surface it hits. But my question is, force is ***mass times acceleration*** and acceleration in both cases is $g$; and being identical their mass is same; so the force on the surface as they hit turns up to be equal. Why is it so?

Comment: momentum is force × time  and not simply equal to force.

Comment: You might refer to an answer of mine to a similar question : https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/646530/301181

Answer (score 1):

The force of gravity is the same on each, but the force the ground exerts on each is different. The maximum force the body experiences will be larger for the object traveling at the faster speed when it hits the ground.

As a simpler model, think of dropping a block onto a spring. The higher the block starts, the greater its change in potential energy will be. All of this energy will be converted into elastic potential energy in the spring once maximum compression is achieved. Therefore, a larger starting height means a larger final elastic potential energy, which means a larger maximum force exerted on the block.

Of course, the ground is not an ideal spring, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a ground with coefficient of restitution $0<e<1$. Assuming that the mass of the ball is $m$, falling from the height $h_1$ and $h_2$, where $h_1 > h_2$, we can get that both balls ended up hitting the ground with velocity $v_1 = \sqrt{2gh_1}$ and $v_2 = \sqrt{2gh_2}$, and the post-hitting velocity should be $v_1' = ev_1$ and $v_2' = ev_2$. It is obvious that $v_1>v_2$.

It is known that impulse $I = m\Delta v$. The change in impulse should be $I_1 = mv_1(1-e)$ and $I_2 = mv_2(1-e)$

We assume that the time that the balls and the ground are in contact is $\Delta t$. The average force exerted on the ball should be $F=\dfrac{I}{\Delta t}$. Since $(1-e)$ is the same, we can get $$F_1-F_2 = \dfrac{mv_1(1-e)-mv_2(1-e)}{\Delta t}=m(1-e)\dfrac{v_1-v_2}{\Delta t}>0$$
Hence $F_1>F_2$, which answers the question.

The question you are encountering is that the force isn't the same throughout the time. The force that the ground is exerting on the ball changes throughout the process.

I hope that this can be of some help to you.